# How to able postgres user to create folders on other user directory?

Tags: linux, postgresql, permissions

Have a function in postgres like as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION enroll_user()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPYTHON3U
AS $$
    import os
    os.mkdir('/home/%s/data' % TD['new']['user'])

    return "MODIFY"
$$;
```

But when call the function from trigger says: `PermisionError[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/test/data'`.

Postgres database runs the function as `postgres` user and `/home/test` is owned by `test` user. When need two users can access to same folder add a group to other user but in postgres can not add other group to access to other users folders.

How to postgres can access and create folders in other users without set a chmod 777 or open a security problem enabling to all other users to access to the test folder home?

Comment: The "easy" way would be to make the `postgres` user the group owner of everything under `/home` and make the perms 775 (or 770).  The saner approach would be (even though it's an ugly cludge) to use `subprocess` and give the postgres user sudo privileges to `sudo mkdir /home/*` without a password.

Comment: Thanks works fine :), but the user is not the owner group of own home?

Comment: That shouldn't matter too much, as long as the postgres user is the only member of the postgres group.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new group called `mygroup`, adding both your new user `alice` and `postgres` to the group, and change the folder's group and grant group write permission to folder.

```
groupadd mygroup
usermod -a -G mygroup alice
usermod -a -G mygroup postgres
chgrp mygroup /home/alice/data
chmod g+rwx /home/alice/data
```